# Slack API returns invalid_email error for valid email address

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am sending API request to *undocumented* API `users.admin.invite` to invite new team members to organization programatically. 
But every time I send the request, it results in error `invalid_email`.
Which is weird, because if I fire the same request from https://{myorg}.slack.com/admin/invites it works.

I've managed to obtain the *again undocumented* client scope token, which is required for this. I've changed to content type to `multipart/form-data`, which seems to be required. But still it does not work..

The relevant code looks like this

```
const options = {
            host: 'myOrg.slack.com',
            path: `/api/users.admin.invite`,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.slackAuthToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept-Language': 'cs,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            },
            formData: {
                "email": event.email,
                "first_name": event.firstName,
                "last_name": event.lastName,
                "real_name": `${event.firstName} ${event.lastName}`,
                 "set_active": true,
                 "resend": true, // Resend the invitation email if the user has already been invited and the email was sent some time ago
            }

 https.request(options) // simplified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug of the undocumented API method [`admin.users.invite`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md) that some emails won't work (its also mentioned in the docs). Nothing much you can do about it I am afraid.

**UPDATE**

The problem was that the request must be send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I am aware of that, (from some your other anser here on SO I guess) but it seems that the problem is elsewhere. When I send data via Postman as application/json, I get the error "invalid_email". But when I send it as "form/multipart" it returns "ok: true".

Comment: Problem is: I need to call it from nodejs (actually node lammbda on AWS) and I just cant get the multipart request right ... So I am stack at the moment.

Comment: I feel like I am blind :) Also the problem might be in Pulumi (serverless framework, I used to deploy to AWS). Sometimes it has trouble converting some code which works locally, to something what would work in the cloud

Comment: I see. But are you sure it actually works with multipart? If so it would be a nice workaround.

Comment: Btw. `application/json` is not supported by this API method. The default is the standard content type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Have you tried that?

Comment: thank you, I've tried the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that works. YES :)